# How to make 'type' property of colDefn more generic in ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-grid

i am new to UI-Grid, i want to display two columns,as name and values. if i double click on cell in values column it get editable i.e its type=text. how to make cell to type checkbox, number or date. this colDefn type should get value from the data set.

code is as follows

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = [{
                    "index": 0,
                    "type": "Text",
                    "id": "name",
                    "title": "Name",
                    "value": "Some Name",
                },
                {
                    "index": 1,
                    "type": "date",
                    "id": "dob",
                    "title": "DOB",
                    "value": "1989-02-21T23:02:31+06:00",
                },
{
                    "index": 2,
                    "type": "number",
                    "id": "age",
                    "title": "Age",
                    "value": 30,
                }];

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
            { field: 'title', displayName: 'Name', enableCellEdit: false, width: '30%'},
            { field: 'value', displayName: 'Value', width: '50%'}]
```

I know to make columns specific to single type. But 
How to make single column containing all types of fields like type="number" or "date" or "boolean(i.e is for checkbox)".

Kindly give your suggestions.

Comment: I found this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hy4TJCJMO94gEGqsM2o0?p=preview Does it help you?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this plnker is for different case. I need to implement a single column which should able to have all fields like(number, checkbox, dropdown, date). I know how to implement column which contain only one field (by specifying type="number" or type="date" ) on which we get entire column same type..i.e column containing only number fields, or only date fields. But in my case i need a column(single column) which should able to contain  number fields, checkbox based on date we provided. kindly provide suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom template, for example this one:

```
<div><div ng-if="!row.entity.typeCol || row.entity.typeCol === 'text' || row.entity.typeCol === 'date' || row.entity.typeCol === 'boolean'" >
  <form
    name="inputForm">
    <input
      type="INPUT_TYPE"
      ng-class="'colt' + col.uid"
      ui-grid-editor
      ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" />
  </form>
</div>

<div ng-if="row.entity.typeCol === 'dropdown'">
  <form
    name="inputForm">
    <select
      ng-class="'colt' + col.uid"
      ui-grid-edit-dropdown
      ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD"
      ng-options="field[editDropdownIdLabel] as field[editDropdownValueLabel] CUSTOM_FILTERS for field in editDropdownOptionsArray">
    </select> 
  </form>
</div>

<div ng-if="row.entity.typeCol === 'file'">
  <form
    name="inputForm">
    <input
      ng-class="'colt' + col.uid"
      ui-grid-edit-file-chooser
      type="file"
      id="files"
      name="files[]"
      ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD"/>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

is a basic example of an editable cell whose type varies depending on the field `typeCol`.

I just copied and pasted the basic templates from ui-grid.edit and put an ng-if around each of them.

I have not tested this, but it's the only way to go, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.., Is there any other alternative solution for overriding default property of ui-grid with our code. because i tried with above solution, but its not working as expected.

Comment: None that I can think of. Sadly the way templates are linked to column is not flexible enough for your needs. But, being UI-grid an open source project you can always come up with a PR and implement the logic you desire.